# Web service for selling intangible goods like file downloads

Tags: ecommerce, service

I have a product that I have developed over the course of 2/3 years in my spare time and wish to bring it to market.

I won't reveal the nature of the product, but it is training based built around PowerPoint and Excel worksheets averaging around 3 to 5mb, and at the moment I have upwords of 10,000 separate files.

My question to you all is, does a service exist to allow me to upload all of these, categorise them nicely together so customers can buy them as 'packs' or 'individually', and handle all payments and delivery of the files? Ideally I could use my own domain name aswell.

I am UK based but would push to US services if cost differences are obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Many people sell goods in this way on eBay and Amazon by sending a protected single use download link in the purchase confirmation email, but it's not an ideal solution and paypal tracking for intangible goods can be tricky, I've heard many horror stories where purchasers simply claim via item not received - as downloads are not tracked the seller doesn't have a leg to stand on.

[www.sythe.org](http://www.sythe.org/) presents itself as, 'the craigslist of virtual goods' their forum may have some more useful information for you.

Outside of dedicated service websites there are plugins like [WP Secure Downloads](http://tomuse.com/wordpress/wp-secure-downloads/) and [WordPress eStore plugin](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-estore-plugin-complete-solution-to-sell-digital-products-from-your-wordpress-blog-securely-1059) which enable you to sell intangibles via your own wordpress based website. I'm sure similar plugins are available for other CMS systems.

Here are a few of the specialist services I'm aware of, **this is not a recommendation**:-

- [Payloadz](https://www.payloadz.com/)
- [E-Junkie](http://www.e-junkie.com/)
- [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/)
- [DigiVendor](http://www.idevspot.com/DigiVendor.php)
- [byteCommerce](http://www.bytecommerce.com/)
- [Plimus](http://www.plimus.com/)
- [Zipidee](http://www.zipidee.com/)

Comment: When referring to Amazon are you talking about the Amazon Marketplace or Amazon Payments? Amazon Payments with PHP script(s) to manage the downloads is common place, easy and relativly safe (from personal experience).

Comment: @EdenCrow both really, it depends on the product. You can use e-books to deliver intangibles, Amazon Marketplace and as you suggest Amazon payments.